# Invalid casting exception on my simple application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net

Here's the gist of it: There is a list of classes at my school. Each class belongs to a single Career. I'm creating the create a new class form, eg. Math, Social Studies, etc. On the form I want a dropdownlist to generate with the available Careers we offer.

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'
>   to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Crear()
{
    CarreraRepository carreraRepository = new CarreraRepository();
    var carreras = carreraRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
    var carrerasList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var carrera in carreras)
    {
        carrerasList.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = carrera.Nombre,
            Value = carrera.ID.ToString()
        });
    }

    ViewData["Carreras"] = carrerasList.AsEnumerable();

    Materia materia = new Materia();
    return View(materia);        
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Crear(Materia materia, FormCollection values)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repo.Add(materia);
        repo.Save();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(materia);

}
```

And here is the View:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.IDCarrera) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.DropDownList("Carrera", (SelectList)ViewData["Carreras"]) %>
    <%--<%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IDCarrera)%>--%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IDCarrera) %>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? My code database schema and code is very simple so the error might be quite obvious to some. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I'm assuming `carreraRepository` is the Entity Framework Context? If so: `'Model1' does not contain a definition for 'FindAll' and no extension method 'FindAll' accepting a first argument of type 'Model1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` If it's supposed to be a model within the database, you get: `'DbSet<carreraRepository>' does not contain a definition for 'FindAll' and no extension method 'FindAll' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<carreraRepository>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put a `SelectList` in the viewdata, instead of the `List<SelectlistItem>` like so:

```
var carreras = carreraRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);
var carrerasList = new SelectList(carreras, "ID", "Nombre");

ViewData["Carreras"] = carrerasList;
```

Comment: That code looks wonderful! Logical and seems like it would work. How do I use this in the View? What do I cast the Carreras dictionary item to?

Comment: because the data contains in `ViewData` is now a `SelectList`, you can just cast to `SelectList`.

Answer (score 0):

To me, since you have your list of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, you could just put that inside the `ViewData` variable, like so:

```
CarreraRepository carreraRepository = new CarreraRepository();
var carreras = carreraRepository.FindAll().OrderBy(x => x.Nombre);

IEnumerable<SimpleListItem> carrerasList = 
    carreras.Select(d => new SelectListItem { 
        Text = d.Nombre, 
        Value = d.ID.ToString() 
    }
);

ViewData["Carreras"] = carrerasList;
```

Then you do this in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Carreras", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Carreras"])
```